# How can I plot Cyclone track form netcdf file?

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf

I have pressure values in NetCDF file for every hour from 0 to 23. I have calculated pressure anomaly for every hour against latitude and longitude. I was able to plot it and I could see the movement of the cyclone from the 0th hour to the 23rd hour but I need to plot the track for that cyclone, I am using python for this and this is something new for me. If someone can help me then it will be beneficial.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**Below are the result of my print(ds):-**

```py
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>

root group (NETCDF4_CLASSIC data model, file format HDF5):

    PP_LBPROC: 0
    PP_LBTIM: 12
    PP_MEAN_PERIOD: 0.0
    contact: rachel.stratton@metoffice.gov.uk
    copyright: (C) Crown Copyright, 2015 the Met Office
    creation_date: 2017-11-29T22:35:54Z
    experiment: CP4
    experiment_id: aj575
    history: 2017-11-29T22:35:54Z: File generated using cmorize v0.1.5b
    institution: Met Office Hadley Centre
    institution_id: MOHC
    model: Regional GA7 configuration on Africa 4.5 km
    model_id: inst
    project_id: IMPALA
    source: Data from Met Office Unified Model
    Conventions: CF-1.5
    dimensions(sizes): time(24), latitude(2100), longitude(2000)
    variables(dimensions): float32 c00409(time, latitude, longitude), int32 latitude_longitude(), float64 time(time), float32 latitude(latitude), float32 longitude(longitude), float64 forecast_period(time), float64 forecast_reference_time()
    groups:
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It’s really hard for us to help without more information. Can you post the results of `print(ds)` as a formatted code block? And anything you can do to show us what you’ve tried and what’s not working would be really helpful. See the guide to [ask]

Comment: Hi, yes I wanted to but I can't because I am a new user so it doesn't allow me to post it. I am basically working on a project where I need to track cyclones in the Madagascar region and the data is in NetCDF format.  so basically what I need to do is track the path of that cyclone from t time to t+1 time in an interval of 6 hours. so I calculated the minimum pressure point at one time but sometimes it is lying anywhere on the map because there can be some points where pressure is lower than cyclone points, so I am confused about how should I approach this problem.

Comment: But I do mean post your code and the result of print(ds) ***as text*** in a [formatted code block](/help/formatting). That’s the recommended way to include a preview of your data - in fact, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: yes, I did edit it, thanks for your help. I am new here

Comment: Ok thanks. And can you also post the code you’ve tried to use and explain what it’s doing and how that’s different from what you need? Try to be really descriptive - describe the types of plots, the dimensions, etc that you’re trying to plot. When you say you want to plot the track, what specifically do you mean?

Comment: Fortunately, I found the solution. Many Thanks :)